# BIBD- block design question combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that a balanced, uniform incomplete design is regular.

For this question, I have no clue where to start, any suggestions?

Comment: Start with the definitions. What's a balanced incomplete block design? What does "uniform" mean? What does "regular" mean?

Comment: it's regular if each vertex exactly occurs in r blocks, and it's uniform if each block contains k-vertices. so which means if each block contains k-vertices then it is regular?

Comment: I cannot parse this question. For me a block design or, better $(v,b,r,k, \lambda)$ design comes with regularness. So, I would like to see your definitions for the terms here. Please consider adding the definitions.

Comment: By definition, if in a k-uniform, regular incomplete design, each pair of vertices occurs together in exactly λ blocks then we say that (S,B) is Balanced incomplete Block with parameter (v,b,r,k,λ).

Comment: I think what Kannappan is asking is, what would a non-regular BIBD look like? Doesn't your definition of BIBD already imply regularity?

Answer (score 2):

This question is likely asking about [pairwise balanced designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design#pairwise_balanced_design).

> A pairwise balanced design (or PBD) is a set X together with a family of subsets of X (which need not have the same size and may contain repeats) such that every pair of distinct elements of X is contained in exactly λ (a positive integer) subsets.

A PBD is said to be *uniform* if each block has the same size, typically denoted k.  A PBD is said to be *regular* if each element belongs to the same number of blocks.

We want to show:

> **Lemma**:  A uniform PBD is regular.

*Proof*:  Take a uniform PBD; so each block has size k.  Pick an element, x say.

Construct a bipartite multigraph:  on the left are the pairs (x,w), for all w (except x), and on the right are the blocks B containing x.  We draw an edge from (x,w) to B if w ∈ B too.

Each vertex on the left has degree λ.  And there are v-1 elements other than x (here v=|X|).  Hence the number of edges in the graph is (v-1)λ.

Each vertex on the right has degree k-1.  Let's suppose there are r vertices on the right.  Hence the number of edges in the graph is r(k-1).

Hence (v-1)λ=r(k-1), and r is determined from v,k,λ (and is independent of the choice of x).  Hence our PBD is regular.